# What's the option to view changes in the DOM inspector in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I think I saw that Chrome has done this before or maybe I set the settings off. In Firefox with Firebug installed, the DOM inspector will make me see what the changes happened in scripts manipulating the HTML [through highlighting the line(s) with yellow]. Is there any option that would make me see what changes in DOM in Chrome?

P.S. well, I like to use Chrome for rapid development from the star and later use any other browsers like firefox. And also, I would like to see the changes happened in jQuery inview plugin https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview and the demo here http://jsbin.com/ugupa

Comment: I think I saw it as well, but it seems it's been disabled... :\

Answer (score 1):

Pressing F12 in chrome opens the developer tools.

The Elements tab shows all the html elements on the page. And using the magnifying glass icon, on the bottom menu, you can select the element on the rendered page and view the html behind it.

As for seeing what happened in jQuery:
If by this you mean you want the see the resulting html after your jQuery code ran, you can also see that under the Elements tab too. 
If you mean that you want to debug jQuery code, you can do this by, using the Sources tab, finding the script that you want to debug and adding some breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, you do not see expected changes in the Elements tab in the dev tools. I just encountered this issue myself, and it looks like it was a glitch. Simply reopen the dev tools and it should be fixed